# Adding new node to hyperledger fabric in real world scenario

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am just started learning how to build the fabric network, but it is still blurry to me how in the real world if we want to add a new node/organization.

I want to build a network of parking providers and an integrator. each parking provider will have its own node. then a new parking provider decides to join the network, are the parking provider set up its own node and give the node information to the integrator (network admin) so that the admin can add its node to the network?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to developing networks, you should follow the Hyperledger Fabric tutroial for [Adding a new Org](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html#adding-an-org-to-a-channel). Try to get this to work first just by running the scripts. The next learning step is to do the same action using command line statements instead. This will give you a better understanding of how it all hangs together. If you are comfortable at that stage, the next thing is to be able to add the same additional organisation but now introduce a Certificate Authority. This will increase your knowledge of the docker scripts and configuration files. The built in shell scripts do not use a CA for the third Org to be added to the "test-network".

If all of this seems overwhelming, then you are off to a good start, because it is. Understand how the network was built before you try to add a new Org. You will better understand the steps required to add more organisations once you do.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world you'll be working through specific use cases and trying to figure out if a blockchain is what you need. Typically a good way to look at it is to identify the business objects of interest (-> these go into world state), then consider how transactions shape them (-> these go into the channel) and from there consider what logic you need (-> i.e., some sort of "state machine" in your smart contract that is deployed as chaincode) and how this logic is to be invoked by peers (-> this is where your client app comes into play).

If that all works you'll be in a position to judge if a blockchain architecture is what you need and want.

Now to your details...

Any node must belong to an organisation so my first guess is that you have one organisation per parking provider and that each parking provider may therefore have one or more nodes (recall node=peer,client,ordering service).

Next I'm a bit unsure what role of the integrator is (beyond network configuration?). For example, you might want to give parking providers autonomy to join or you might want to impose a central authority for organisational membership? Also you might want to have the integrator do things that the parking providers are less enthusastic about (e.g., ordering service?).

I'll guess you'll figure those details out